# How can i add a search functionality to filter the list of names

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had retrieved a list of employees from the database using php code and I want to add a search functionality to filter the names.

How can I do this using js or php? I got struct in this from last one week, searched online but unable to find the solution.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Search Name">

<ul id="myUL" class="contacts-list">
  <?php
  $status=1;
  $sql1 =  $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE status='$status'");
  $sql1->execute();

  if($sql1->rowCount() > 0) { 
    while($row = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  ?>
      <li>
        <a href="messages.php?employee_id=<?php echo $row['employee_id']; ?>">
          <div class="contacts-list-info">
            <span class="contacts-list-name">
          <?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname']; ?>
            <small class="contacts-list-date pull-right">
              <?php if($row['status'] == '1') { echo 'Online'; } else { echo 'Offline'; } ?>
            </small>
          </span>
            <span class="contacts-list-msg">
            <?php echo $row['role']; ?>
          </span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
  <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please also provide your database structure also, which field you want to search.

Comment: Filtering can be done on server side and client side both. Which one are you preferring?

Comment: Do you want to filter the database search(php), or do you want to filter the webpage(js)?

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia, i want on client side,  In the php code i have written, it will gets retrive the list of employee names. i want to add search button at the top to filter the names.

Comment: Again there are two options. You can send a request to the server with the search text and send filtered data and replace the html on a successful ajax call. And the other option is to implement the real-time search, for that you will have to play with the JavaScript objects. [Check this W3Schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter just on the client side, you can do something like this:

Get all contacts (e. g. `li` tags) and apply a filter based on the users input.

```js
function search() {
  var input = document.getElementById('search').value.toLowerCase();
  var contacts = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      contacts[i].style.display = "block";
    } else if (!contacts[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      contacts[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search()"> Enter something to filter
<br>
<ul>
  <li>Some Dude</li>
  <li>Some Dudine</li>
  <li>John Doe</li>
  <li>Erica Doe</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like query as below:

```
Select * from employee where status LIKE '%$status%';
```

As per your query you can get employee status from database.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Already i have a list of employees from my select statement in li tag. for that list i want to apply filter.

Comment: But you can search employee name by query also, please provide your database sturecture.

Comment: You can get employee name direct from database also, using select query.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do. If you want suggestion box like in search input field than u can simple use ajax request to fetch suggestion form DB and add typehead js library and than paste following code.

```
$('#id').typeahead({
                ajax: {
                    url: '../employeeList',
                    method: 'post',
                    triggerLength: 1
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a working exapmle** for filtering in client-side using your structure.

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var input = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var people = document.getElementsByClassName("contacts-list-info");
  for (var i of people) {
    if (i.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      i.closest("li").style.display = "list-item";
    } else {
      i.closest("li").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Search Name">

<ul id="myUL" class="contacts-list">
  <li>
    <a href="messages.php?employee_id=1">
      <div class="contacts-list-info">
        <span class="contacts-list-name">
          Test Test
          <small class="contacts-list-date pull-right">
            Offline
          </small>
        </span>
        <span class="contacts-list-msg">
            Manager
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="messages.php?employee_id=1">
      <div class="contacts-list-info">
        <span class="contacts-list-name">
          Second Test
          <small class="contacts-list-date pull-right">
            Online
          </small>
        </span>
        <span class="contacts-list-msg">
            Manager
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="messages.php?employee_id=1">
      <div class="contacts-list-info">
        <span class="contacts-list-name">
          Third Test
          <small class="contacts-list-date pull-right">
            Online
          </small>
        </span>
        <span class="contacts-list-msg">
            Employee
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="messages.php?employee_id=1">
      <div class="contacts-list-info">
        <span class="contacts-list-name">
          Fourth Test
          <small class="contacts-list-date pull-right">
            Offline
          </small>
        </span>
        <span class="contacts-list-msg">
            Team member
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```